# VBA Open excel, modify(Rank), Close excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use Excel (2013) to open an existing excel document, modify it by adding ranking code, and then closing it. My code will open the excel document but I am not sure how to implement the ByVal Target As Range section. I do not know enough about VBA to put this macro within a macro. Suggestions?

```
Sub Macro1()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\X\Desktop\test\program2.xlsx"

     Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column <> 13 Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    'Dim SortRange As Range
    Set SortRange = Range(("A1"), Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp))
    SortRange.Sort Key1:=Range("M2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End Sub

    'File to Macro (Should be same as above)

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\X\Desktop\test\program2.xlsx" _
        , AccessMode:=xlShared
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! To use the `Worksheet_Change` sub, you'll need to put code in the appropriate module. Here's a quick screenshot: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1zoduu0&s=8#.U3Pml0ZdWv8

Answer (score 0):

Interesting try but quite wrong.  You must come from JavaScript or something where one can nest routines (JS has closures).  Sadly, no such funky stuff in VBA.  Please remove the inner sub outside the outer sub and place in the module "behind" the sheet it relates to.

Answer (score 0):

Call the second sub from within the first sub, but don't nest them inside.

```
Sub Macro1()
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\X\Desktop\test\program2.xlsx"

    Worksheets("program2.xlsx").Activate     
        Call Worksheet_Change

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\X\Desktop\test\program2.xlsx" _
    , AccessMode:=xlShared
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column <> 13 Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
'Dim SortRange As Range
Set SortRange = Range(("A1"), Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp))
SortRange.Sort Key1:=Range("M2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```